How to change default values of nested entities created with factories?
My data model looks like this:

An Order contains between 1 and N Products, a Product has a single Category.
I have 3 Factories, one for each entity: OrderFactory, ProductFactory, CategoryFactory. In them, I setup default data:
namespace Database\Factories;

use App\Category;
use App\Product;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;

class ProductFactory extends Factory
{
    protected $model = Product::class;

    public function definition()
    {
        $name = $this->faker->realText(20);
        return [
            'category_id' => Category::factory(),
            'reference' => str_replace(' ', '', $name),
            'name' => $name,
            'price' => $this->faker->randomFloat(2, 1.00, 200.00),
        ];
    }
}


namespace Database\Factories;

use App\Category;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;

class CategoryFactory extends Factory
{
    protected $model = Category::class;

    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'label' => $this->faker->realText(20),
            'description' => $this->faker->text,
        ];
    }
}

I want for one particular test to create an Order containing 5 products of a Category named my specific category label. I tried to do it like so:
$order = Order::factory()
    ->state([
        'number' => 014789012,
    ])
    ->has(
        Product::factory()
            ->count(3)
            ->has(
                Category::factory()->state([
                    'label' => 'my specific category label',
                ])
            )
    )
    ->create();

But the Category->label is not edited and remains the default one defined in CategoryFactory. Why?

I made a mistake by using has() instead of for() on my Product <=> Category relation: as it is a OneToMany relationship, we need to use for(), like so:
$order = Order::factory()
    ->state([
        'number' => 014789012,
    ])
    ->has(
        Product::factory()
            ->count(3)
            ->for(
                Category::factory()->state([
                    'label' => 'my specific category label',
                ])
            )
    )
    ->create();


You can do like this too I guess
# First, create the category
$category = Category::factory()->create([
    'label' => 'my specific category label',
]);

# after,  link to the category
$order = Order::factory()
    ->state([
        'number' => '014789012', # Make sure the number is a String or Number
    ])
    ->has(
        Product::factory()
            ->count(5) # Set to 5
            ->state([
                'category_id' => $category->id, # Assin the ID of the category
            ])
    )
    ->create();

